# Three post requests to the same method, how to run the method just once time sharing the result to the three of them?

Tags: python, flask, request

I have three post flask requests that goes to 3 different APIs, get_max, get_min, get mean.

These three APIs are calling the same method, because a method returns all the information in a dictionary.

How could I just run the method one time without changing the three API calls and not using self? Is there any pattern for this?

API Calls:

```
self.app.add_url_rule(API + '/get_max', 'get_max', self.get_max, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
self.app.add_url_rule(API + '/get_min', 'get_min', self.get_min, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
self.app.add_url_rule(API + '/get_mean', 'get_mean', self.get_mean, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Shared method:

```
def get_all(self, data):
    result={}
    result["max"] = data["price"].max()
    result["min"] = data["price"].min()
    result["mean"] = data["price"].mean()
    return result
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code to see how you made it

Comment: Thanks @azro I updated a bit the question.

Comment: You want like a cache, when you call the same method in a given amount of time the result is directly returned and not computed again ? Read on https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/